# F# keyword 'Some'

Tags: f#, keyword

F# keyword '**Some**' - what does it mean?

Answer (score 52):

`Some` is not a keyword. There is an `option` type however, which is a discriminated union containing two things:

1. `Some` which holds a value of some type.
2. `None` which represents lack of value.

It's defined as:

```
type 'a option =
    | None
    | Some of 'a
```

It acts kind of like a nullable type, where you want to have an object which can hold a value of some type or have no value at all.

```
let stringRepresentationOfSomeObject (x : 'a option) =
    match x with
    | None -> "NONE!"
    | Some(t) -> t.ToString()
```

Answer (score 8):

Can check out [Discriminated Unions in F#](http://lorgonblog.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!701679AD17B6D310!172.entry) for more info on DUs in general and the option type (Some, None) in particular.  As a previous answer says, Some is just a union-case of the option<'a> type, which is a particularly common/useful example of an algebraic data type.

Answer (score 7):

`Some` is used to specify an option type, or in other words, a type that may or may not exist.

F# is different from most languages in that control flow is mostly done through pattern matching as opposed to traditional if/else logic.

In traditional if/else logic, you may see something like this:

```
if (isNull(x)) {
   do ...  
} else {         //x exists
   do ...  
}
```

With pattern matching logic, matching we need a similar way to execute certain code if a value is null, or in F# syntax, `None`

Thus we would have the same code as

```
match x with 
  | None -> do ...
  | Some x -> do ...
```