# Array indexer within choose() won't work

Tags: f#

Please pardon my dust here while I am trying to learn F#

I have a function that gives me a Seq of Arrays read from a CSV file. Each element of those arrays represent one column data.

```
let file = readFile("""C:\path\to\file.csv""")
```

The first column is dates which I am trying to fetch here is my code

```
let dates = 
file
|> Seq.skip(1)
|> Seq.choose(fun x -> x.[0])
```

I am getting the following compile error

```
error FS0001: This expression was expected to have type    'a option
```

Am I using it wrong ? When I point mouse to 'x', intellisense tells me x is of type string[]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you actually wanted was

```
let dates = 
file
|> Seq.skip(1)
|> Seq.map(fun x -> x.[0])
```

`Seq.choose` does filtering as well, but as you don't use the filtering you only need to use `map`

Answer (score 3):

I got it fixed. [Some()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450335/f-keyword-some) is what I wanted.

```
let dates = 
file
|> Seq.skip(1)
|> Seq.choose(fun x -> Some(x.[0]))
```